# How can my app open Siri shortcuts recording phrase view

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirishortcuts

How can I open from my app the Siri shortcut view where the custom phrase is recorded, with the information of a specific shortcut that my app donated. Also how can I delete a donated shortcut. I tried assigning an identifier for the interaction to be able to delete it, but don't know how to implement the delete that is in the documentation.

```
let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
interaction.identifier = intentIdentifier 

class func delete(with identifiers: [String], 
       completion: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

I'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone need it. To delete a donated shortcut call:

```
INInteraction.delete(with: [deleteIntentIdentifier!]
```

Where [deleteIntentIdentifier!] is an array of the identifiers of the shortcuts that you want to delete.

Regarding the recording phrase to Siri, I copied and edited the necessary code from SoupChef.

Comment: Did you find out if its possible to list interactions that have been donated? I want to only display an "Add To Siri" button if it has not been done yet